# dspace create-administrator loop after yes

Tags: dspace

After there was a database issue, every access to the database did throw an error. (Was ill, and the old admin found a mistake that all files bigger than 1MB could not get uploaded, i think might have been a tomcat issue. He started to delete wrong unused files. Then the dspace installation was suddenly not working and giving all the time an error.) Not sure if there an autoupgrade of postgres happened. I decided to delete the database and make it new. After the install instructions.
However when I started dspace create-administrator It never finishes it, after the y for yes, he is in an endless loop, at least he does not finish it or gives an error message. This has happened to me the second time the last time I only solved it when I reinstalled the whole server.

Therefore I cannot Login.
Is there a postgres direct command line to create the admin for dspace?

System debain
Backend version 7.1.1 first 7.1.1 changed now to 7.2

Flyway 6.5.7, tried to change pomto 8.5.1, 7.0.2 and some others gave me all the time and error

Postgres 13.5, tried with 14.2 and 12.10 did not change

maven 3.6.3-5

tomcat9 9.0.43-2

java first 11 now 17

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
Drop database
createdb --username=postgres --owner=dspace --encoding=UNICODE dspace
psql --username=postgres dspace -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;"

[dspace]/bin/dspace database migrate
[dspace]/bin/dspace create-administrator
```

Tried with running dspace instance and running tomcat and solr, and also with everything not running

Expected behavior
create Database user

Answer (score 1):

I set a new server up, now this part worked and also dspace angular was ableto install. But now it only shows for the administrator only import and export and not more items.
seam to get this message in the browser developer console:

```
Autofocus processing was blocked because a document already has a focused element.
```

Comment: Solved, installed new, now working